# undefined method `perform_asynch' while using sidekiq in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

I have written a worker:

```
class XmlParseWorker

  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: "parsing"

  def perform
   ........
  end
end
```

when I try to run it in the console with:

```
XmlParseWorker.perform_asynch()
```

I get an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `perform_asynch' for XmlParseWorker:Class
```

I have added sidekiq to my gemfile:

```
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sinatra' , require: false
gem 'slim'
```

And ran bundle install.

I ran redis:

```
redis-server
```

And the sidekiq queue:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -q parsing
```

But I don't even see it in the sideqik web admin.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it's supposed to be `perform_async`

Comment: You are right! Damn.. the kinds of stupid mistakes you waste a whole day on... thank you!